# Consulta Bases de datos(Algebra relacional)

Tags: base-de-datos, division, álgebra-relacional

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La consulta es,*"Nombre de todos los docentes (Tipo D) que no han realizados cursos o que han usado la sede 101."*

Estoy intentado resolver este ejercicio mediante una división:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando hago la operación manualmente las tupas de salida no son las esperadas, hay alguna otra forma de resolver esta consulta? no entiendo que es lo que anda mal en mi operación.

Se que r÷s =[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
y que en la operación de división buscamos todas las combinaciones de tuplas menos las combinaciones de tuplas que no cumplen la condición y eso sera igual a las tuplas que si la cumplen

Answer (score 0):

La división se usaría para docentes que hayan hecho todos los cursos, para ningún curso es tan simple como comprobar que no estén en la tabla de `CURSOS REALIZADOS`, directamente con un operador `NOT IN`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En MySQL sería algo así:

```
SELECT Nombre FROM (
    SELECT * FROM persona
      WHERE Tipo='D'  
  ) p WHERE Ced NOT IN (
    SELECT Doc_Est
      FROM cursos_realizados  
  ) OR Ced IN (
    SELECT Doc_Est
      FROM cursos_realizados
      WHERE Sede=101  
  );
```